# Dynamically change CSS styles of input field upon successful validation without submitting form

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically update the CSS styles of an input field as soon as it successfully validates, without requiring a form submission. Currently, I can only trigger validation upon form submission, and I want the input field border to turn green dynamically when all validators match, providing a visual response to users without having to submit the form. Is there a way to achieve this without using JavaScript?

Comment: you have to use `JavaScript`. You may need `JavaScript` to validate data directly in browser and use `JavaScript` to change `CSS`. Or you need `JavaScript` to send data to server (which will validate and send only result without full page) and get result, and use `JavaScript` to change `CSS`